# PHP - QR Image HTML Email

Tags: php, image, email, qr-code

This is an old post.  Please refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35467834/php-embed-generated-image-from-external-file-into-html-email) for current issue

Comment: How exactly are you generating your emails?

Comment: Can you show us more of the code that inserts `<img src="data:image/png;base64,'.$base_64_encoder.'" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">` or what the generated html looks like?

Comment: Also is that script `turnstile.php` outputting a PNG image?

Comment: @SergeyVidusov - pardon the lack of formatting, I'm not sure how to do it in comments! :(

The email-generation code looks as follows:
'$email_message = '
 ...
   <table rules="all" style="border-color: #666;" cellpadding="10">
     <tr>
       <th>Name</th>
       ...
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>'.$record["full_name"].'</td>
      ...
     </tr>
   </table>
   <h2>The event information is as follows...</h2>
   <img src="data:image/png;base64,'.$base_64_encoder.'" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">
...

Comment: @jostrander - Yes, that turnstile.php script is outputting a PNG image

Comment: Can you debug the contents of $base_64_encoder before being sent off as an email, or preview the email before being sent by dumping it to file?

Comment: @dannyk You should add the email-generating code to your question. And I'd suggest dumping the $email_message or $base_64_encoder content somewhere to see if the <img> is indeed being filled with anything.

Comment: @jostrander at the moment, all I'm getting when I run php resend_email.php from the terminal is an error message that says "base64_encode() expects parameter 1 to be string"

Comment: @dannyk Looks like `CogentQrImage::pngBytes()` is not creating anything useful, then.

Comment: It's probably creating a byte array instead of a string, `file_get_contents()` to that URL should fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks (everyone) for the help, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't dump the base64 src into the body of the email, you have to treat it like an attachment. Use a content header in place of the src. Here's a snippet of how gmail does it.

Email Content Header

```
Content-Type: image/png; name="InlineImage.png"
Content-Disposition: inline; filename="InlineImage.png"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-ID: <ii_ikqclluk0_152ed84122ba57fd>
X-Attachment-Id: ii_ikqclluk0_152ed84122ba57fd

--base64 here--
```

HTML

```
<img src="cid:ii_ikqclluk0_152ed84122ba57fd">
```