# PHP - Embed Generated Image from External File into HTML email

Tags: php, html, image, email, embedded-resource

I have a sign-up form. When someone signs up, they immediately receive an email (in HTML format) with the following information:

1) Their sign-up information (Name, P#, Email, etc.)

What I need is the following:

1) After sign-up, in the email the user receives, there needs to be a png-image that is generated by an external script. At the moment, I am using PEAR to generate/send the email (AOK) and Mail_Mime::addHTMLImage() to add the image, but alas, with no luck. All I get when I send the email is a broken image with my alt text appearing.  It's important to keep in mind that I am generating the image (to be used in the HTML email) from an external script.

The code I'm using to try and grab the image (from the external script) is as follows:

```
$mime->addHTMLImage(get_template_directory_uri()."/qr_code_generator.php?code=", "image/png");
```

Also, not sure if it helps, but I'm using http://phpqrcode.sourceforge.net/ for the QR code generation

Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I would assume that you at least need a code?

Comment: @PeeHaa The code that is to come after the '?code=' is what gets auto-generated when a user signs up for the event.  So when someone signs up for the event, they get a confirmation code generated for them that I am trying to get embedded in a png image (qr code, more specifically) which will then be added to my PHP HTML email

Answer (score 0):

I answered most of this in your previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35442997/php-qr-image-html-email/35448295#35448295%20%22here%22.).

The likely issue again is that you can't embedded base64 encoded images directly into the body of the email, you have to treat them like attachments. The way you do that is with a content section and an appropriate content id.

Check out the documentation for the addHTMLImage method.
https://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.mail.mail-mime.addhtmlimage.php

It's not the best documentation but check it out and my other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35442997/php-qr-image-html-email/35448295#35448295%20%22here%22.). That should give you enough to solve the issue.

Comment: So those headers you detailed in your post to my previous question are properties I can just add to my current $headers array?  Thanks

Comment: Building emails from scratch is not fun. You're usually better off using a library. In your case since you're so close to success with Pear, I would stick with that and just try to sort out the 'content_id' parameter in the addHTMLImage method.

Comment: Without more info on your $headers array it's impossible to say. If you want to see more about how emails are built, send an email to a [mailinator](http://mailinator.com) account and click on view original to see the raw code. If you want an alternative you can try a simple class I use. It's on my site [here](http://offthebricks.com/?page=programming&sub=web&item=email). Happy emailing

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the help, I really appreciate it!

Comment: These are what my headers currently look like:

'$headers = array(
  'From' => $from,
  'To' => $to,
  'Subject' => $subject,
  'Content-Type' => 'text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1',
  'Content-Transfer-Encoding' => 'base64' 
 );'

Comment: Those headers are your primary email headers. Attachments and embedded images have their data stored in sub content areas that also have their own headers. I suggest you stick with a library. If you want to do it from scratch then you'll want to do a lot more reading on how email attachments work.

Comment: In the highly likely event I change my website around, here's [a link to the GitHub page](https://github.com/mircerlancerous/SendMail) for the PHP email class I use